# Firebase FCM returning 403 SenderId mismatch PERMISSION_DENIED while trying to push a notification

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to setup a dev environment for developing with FCM and I'm getting this error.
I'm using the configuration of out-of-box and it is been loaded properly (I've debugged).
I'm working with java 8 and spring 2.2.12 and firebase-admin 7.1.0.

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectt-82004/messages:send
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SenderId mismatch",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**What I've tried so far**

- Create a new project and a new key
- There was an old documented error where the services were not activated by default. I've checked the services and all of them are active.
- Also, the user appears to have enough privileges.
- I've also updated the library to the latest version (it also happened with the previous version)

Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

**Same code, later on the following day, without any changes to the code, it started working. So the conclusion was that there was some problem with the service itself.**